# Kivy camera2 api get buffer

Tags: python, android, kivy, android-camera2, buildozer

I'm looking for a way to get a buffer from camera2 API in Kivy, like with camera_android.
I am using the code from the Color blind project :https://github.com/inclement/colour-blind-camera/blob/master/camera2/camera2.py

THANKS.

## camera_android

```
from jnius import autoclass, PythonJavaClass, java_method
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.graphics import Fbo, Callback, Rectangle
from kivy.core.camera import CameraBase
import threading


Camera = autoclass('android.hardware.Camera')
SurfaceTexture = autoclass('android.graphics.SurfaceTexture')
GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = autoclass(
    'android.opengl.GLES11Ext').GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
ImageFormat = autoclass('android.graphics.ImageFormat')


class PreviewCallback(PythonJavaClass):
    """
    Interface used to get back the preview frame of the Android Camera
    """
    __javainterfaces__ = ('android.hardware.Camera$PreviewCallback', )

    def __init__(self, callback):
        super(PreviewCallback, self).__init__()
        self._callback = callback

    @java_method('([BLandroid/hardware/Camera;)V')
    def onPreviewFrame(self, data, camera):
        self._callback(data, camera)


class CameraAndroid(CameraBase):
    """
    Implementation of CameraBase using Android API
    """

    _update_ev = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._android_camera = None
        self._preview_cb = PreviewCallback(self._on_preview_frame)
        self._buflock = threading.Lock()
        super(CameraAndroid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        self._release_camera()

    def init_camera(self):
        self._release_camera()
        self._android_camera = Camera.open(self._index)
        params = self._android_camera.getParameters()
        width, height = self._resolution
        params.setPreviewSize(width, height)
        params.setFocusMode('continuous-picture')
        self._android_camera.setParameters(params)
        # self._android_camera.setDisplayOrientation()
        self.fps = 30.

        pf = params.getPreviewFormat()
        assert(pf == ImageFormat.NV21)  # default format is NV21
        self._bufsize = int(ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(pf) / 8. *
                            width * height)

        self._camera_texture = Texture(width=width, height=height,
                                       target=GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
                                       colorfmt='rgba')
        self._surface_texture = SurfaceTexture(int(self._camera_texture.id))
        self._android_camera.setPreviewTexture(self._surface_texture)

        self._fbo = Fbo(size=self._resolution)
        self._fbo['resolution'] = (float(width), float(height))
        self._fbo.shader.fs = '''
            #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
            #ifdef GL_ES
                precision highp float;
            #endif

            /* Outputs from the vertex shader */
            varying vec4 frag_color;
            varying vec2 tex_coord0;

            /* uniform texture samplers */
            uniform sampler2D texture0;
            uniform samplerExternalOES texture1;
            uniform vec2 resolution;

            void main()
            {
                vec2 coord = vec2(tex_coord0.y * (
                    resolution.y / resolution.x), 1. -tex_coord0.x);
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, tex_coord0);
            }
        '''
        with self._fbo:
            self._texture_cb = Callback(lambda instr:
                                        self._camera_texture.bind)
            Rectangle(size=self._resolution)

    def _release_camera(self):
        if self._android_camera is None:
            return

        self.stop()
        self._android_camera.release()
        self._android_camera = None

        # clear texture and it'll be reset in `_update` pointing to new FBO
        self._texture = None
        del self._fbo, self._surface_texture, self._camera_texture

    def _on_preview_frame(self, data, camera):
        with self._buflock:
            if self._buffer is not None:
                # add buffer back for reuse
                self._android_camera.addCallbackBuffer(self._buffer)
            self._buffer = data
        # check if frame grabbing works
        # print self._buffer, len(self.frame_data)

    def _refresh_fbo(self):
        self._texture_cb.ask_update()
        self._fbo.draw()

    def start(self):
        super(CameraAndroid, self).start()

        with self._buflock:
            self._buffer = None
        for k in range(2):  # double buffer
            buf = b'\x00' * self._bufsize
            self._android_camera.addCallbackBuffer(buf)
        self._android_camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(self._preview_cb)

        self._android_camera.startPreview()
        if self._update_ev is not None:
            self._update_ev.cancel()
        self._update_ev = Clock.schedule_interval(self._update, 1 / self.fps)

    def stop(self):
        super(CameraAndroid, self).stop()
        if self._update_ev is not None:
            self._update_ev.cancel()
            self._update_ev = None
        self._android_camera.stopPreview()

        self._android_camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(None)
        # buffer queue cleared as well, to be recreated on next start
        with self._buflock:
            self._buffer = None

    def _update(self, dt):
        self._surface_texture.updateTexImage()
        self._refresh_fbo()
        if self._texture is None:
            self._texture = self._fbo.texture
            self.dispatch('on_load')
        self._copy_to_gpu()

    def _copy_to_gpu(self):
        """
        A dummy placeholder (the image is already in GPU) to be consistent
        with other providers.
        """
        self.dispatch('on_texture')

    def grab_frame(self):
        """
        Grab current frame (thread-safe, minimal overhead)
        """
        with self._buflock:
            if self._buffer is None:
                return None
            buf = self._buffer.tostring()
            return buf

    def decode_frame(self, buf):
        """
        Decode image data from grabbed frame.

        This method depends on OpenCV and NumPy - however it is only used for
        fetching the current frame as a NumPy array, and not required when
        this :class:`CameraAndroid` provider is simply used by a
        :class:`~kivy.uix.camera.Camera` widget.
        """
        import numpy as np
        from cv2 import cvtColor

        w, h = self._resolution
        arr = np.fromstring(buf, 'uint8').reshape((h + h / 2, w))
        arr = cvtColor(arr, 93)  # NV21 -> BGR
        return arr

    def read_frame(self):
        """
        Grab and decode frame in one call
        """
        return self.decode_frame(self.grab_frame())

    @staticmethod
    def get_camera_count():
        """
        Get the number of available cameras.
        """
        return Camera.getNumberOfCameras()
```

## color blind camera

```
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.graphics import Fbo, Callback, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import (BooleanProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, OptionProperty, ListProperty)
from kivy.clock import Clock

from jnius import autoclass, cast, PythonJavaClass, java_method, JavaClass, MetaJavaClass, JavaMethod

import logging
from enum import Enum

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

CameraManager = autoclass("android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager")
PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
Context = autoclass("android.content.Context")
context = cast("android.content.Context", PythonActivity.mActivity)

CameraDevice = autoclass("android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice")
CaptureRequest = autoclass("android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest")
CameraCharacteristics = autoclass("android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics")

ArrayList = autoclass('java.util.ArrayList')
JavaArray = autoclass('java.lang.reflect.Array')

SurfaceTexture = autoclass('android.graphics.SurfaceTexture')
Surface = autoclass('android.view.Surface')
GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES = autoclass(
    'android.opengl.GLES11Ext').GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
ImageFormat = autoclass('android.graphics.ImageFormat')

Handler = autoclass("android.os.Handler")
Looper = autoclass("android.os.Looper")

MyStateCallback = autoclass("net.inclem.camera2.MyStateCallback")
CameraActions = autoclass("net.inclem.camera2.MyStateCallback$CameraActions")
# MyStateCallback = autoclass("org.kivy.android.MyStateCallback")

MyCaptureSessionCallback = autoclass("net.inclem.camera2.MyCaptureSessionCallback")
CameraCaptureEvents = autoclass("net.inclem.camera2.MyCaptureSessionCallback$CameraCaptureEvents")

_global_handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

class LensFacing(Enum):
    """Values copied from CameraCharacteristics api doc, as pyjnius
    lookup doesn't work on some devices.
    """
    LENS_FACING_FRONT = 0
    LENS_FACING_BACK = 1
    LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL = 2

class ControlAfMode(Enum):
    CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE = 4

class ControlAeMode(Enum):
    CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON = 1

class Runnable(PythonJavaClass):
    __javainterfaces__ = ['java/lang/Runnable']

    def __init__(self, func):
        super(Runnable, self).__init__()
        self.func = func

    @java_method('()V')
    def run(self):
        try:
            self.func()
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()


class PyCameraInterface(EventDispatcher):
    """
    Provides an API for querying details of the cameras available on Android.
    """

    camera_ids = []

    cameras = ListProperty()

    java_camera_characteristics = {}

    java_camera_manager = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        logger.info("Starting camera interface init")
        self.java_camera_manager = cast("android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager",
                                    context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE))

        self.camera_ids = self.java_camera_manager.getCameraIdList()
        characteristics_dict = self.java_camera_characteristics
        camera_manager = self.java_camera_manager
        logger.info("Got basic java objects")
        for camera_id in self.camera_ids:
            logger.info(f"Getting data for camera {camera_id}")
            characteristics_dict[camera_id] = camera_manager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera_id)
            logger.info("Got characteristics dict")

            self.cameras.append(PyCameraDevice(
                camera_id=camera_id,
                java_camera_manager=camera_manager,
                java_camera_characteristics=characteristics_dict[camera_id],
            ))
            logger.info(f"Finished interpreting camera {camera_id}")

    def select_cameras(self, **conditions):
        options = self.cameras
        outputs = []
        for camera in cameras:
            for key, value in conditions.items():
                if getattr(camera, key) != value:
                    break
            else:
                outputs.append(camera)

        return outputs

class PyCameraDevice(EventDispatcher):

    camera_id = StringProperty()

    output_texture = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)

    preview_active = BooleanProperty(False)
    preview_texture = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)
    preview_resolution = ListProperty()
    preview_fbo = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)
    java_preview_surface_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    java_preview_surface = ObjectProperty(None)
    java_capture_request = ObjectProperty(None)
    java_surface_list = ObjectProperty(None)
    java_capture_session = ObjectProperty(None)

    connected = BooleanProperty(False)

    supported_resolutions = ListProperty()
    # TODO: populate this

    facing = OptionProperty("UNKNOWN", options=["UNKNOWN", "FRONT", "BACK", "EXTERNAL"])

    java_camera_characteristics = ObjectProperty()
    java_camera_manager = ObjectProperty()
    java_camera_device = ObjectProperty()
    java_stream_configuration_map = ObjectProperty()

    _open_callback = ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type("on_opened")
        self.register_event_type("on_closed")
        self.register_event_type("on_disconnected")
        self.register_event_type("on_error")

        self._java_state_callback_runnable = Runnable(self._java_state_callback)
        self._java_state_java_callback = MyStateCallback(self._java_state_callback_runnable)

        self._java_capture_session_callback_runnable = Runnable(self._java_capture_session_callback)
        self._java_capture_session_java_callback = MyCaptureSessionCallback(
            self._java_capture_session_callback_runnable)

        self._populate_camera_characteristics()

    def on_opened(self, instance):
        pass
    def on_closed(self, instance):
        pass
    def on_disconnected(self, instance):
        pass
    def on_error(self, instance, error):
        pass

    def close(self):
        self.java_camera_device.close()

    def _populate_camera_characteristics(self):
        logger.info("Populating camera characteristics")
        self.java_stream_configuration_map = self.java_camera_characteristics.get(
            CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
        logger.info("Got stream configuration map")

        self.supported_resolutions = [
            (size.getWidth(), size.getHeight()) for size in
            self.java_stream_configuration_map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture(0).getClass())]
        logger.info("Got supported resolutions")

        facing = self.java_camera_characteristics.get(
            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        logger.info(f"Got facing: {facing}")
        if facing == LensFacing.LENS_FACING_BACK.value:  # CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK:
            self.facing = "BACK"
        elif facing == LensFacing.LENS_FACING_FRONT.value:  # CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT:
            self.facing = "FRONT"
        elif facing == LensFacing.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL.value:  # CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL:
            self.facing = "EXTERNAL"
        else:
            raise ValueError("Camera id {} LENS_FACING is unknown value {}".format(self.camera_id, facing))
        logger.info(f"Finished initing camera {self.camera_id}")

    def __str__(self):
        return "<PyCameraDevice facing={}>".format(self.facing)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def open(self, callback=None):
        self._open_callback = callback
        self.java_camera_manager.openCamera(
            self.camera_id,
            self._java_state_java_callback,
            _global_handler
        )

    def _java_state_callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        action = MyStateCallback.camera_action.toString()
        camera_device = MyStateCallback.camera_device

        self.java_camera_device = camera_device

        logger.info("CALLBACK: camera event {}".format(action))
        if action == "OPENED":
            self.dispatch("on_opened", self)
            self.connected = True
        elif action == "DISCONNECTED":
            self.dispatch("on_disconnected", self)
            self.connected = False
        elif action == "CLOSED":
            self.dispatch("on_closed", self)
            self.connected = False
        elif action == "ERROR":
            error = MyStateCallback.camera_error
            self.dispatch("on_error", self, error)
            self.connected = False
        elif action == "UNKNOWN":
            print("UNKNOWN camera state callback item")
            self.connected = False
        else:
            raise ValueError("Received unknown camera action {}".format(action))

        if self._open_callback is not None:
            self._open_callback(self, action)

    def start_preview(self, resolution):
        if self.java_camera_device is None:
            raise ValueError("Camera device not yet opened, cannot create preview stream")

        if resolution not in self.supported_resolutions:
            raise ValueError(
                "Tried to open preview with resolution {}, not in supported resolutions {}".format(
                    resolution, self.supported_resolutions))

        if self.preview_active:
            raise ValueError("Preview already active, can't start again without stopping first")

        logger.info("Creating capture stream with resolution {}".format(resolution))

        self.preview_resolution = resolution
        self._prepare_preview_fbo(resolution)
        self.preview_texture = Texture(
            width=resolution[0], height=resolution[1], target=GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, colorfmt="rgba")
        logger.info("Texture id is {}".format(self.preview_texture.id))
        self.java_preview_surface_texture = SurfaceTexture(int(self.preview_texture.id))
        self.java_preview_surface_texture.setDefaultBufferSize(*resolution)
        self.java_preview_surface = Surface(self.java_preview_surface_texture)

        self.java_capture_request = self.java_camera_device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        self.java_capture_request.addTarget(self.java_preview_surface)
        self.java_capture_request.set(
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, ControlAfMode.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE.value)  # CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
        self.java_capture_request.set(
            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, ControlAeMode.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON.value)  # CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON)

        self.java_surface_list = ArrayList()
        self.java_surface_list.add(self.java_preview_surface)

        self.java_camera_device.createCaptureSession(
            self.java_surface_list,
            self._java_capture_session_java_callback,
            _global_handler,
        )

        return self.preview_fbo.texture

    def _prepare_preview_fbo(self, resolution):
        self.preview_fbo = Fbo(size=resolution)
        self.preview_fbo['resolution'] = [float(f) for f in resolution]
        self.preview_fbo.shader.fs = """
            #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
            #ifdef GL_ES
                precision highp float;
            #endif

            /* Outputs from the vertex shader */
            varying vec4 frag_color;
            varying vec2 tex_coord0;

            /* uniform texture samplers */
            uniform sampler2D texture0;
            uniform samplerExternalOES texture1;
            uniform vec2 resolution;

            void main()
            {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, tex_coord0);
            }
        """
        with self.preview_fbo:
            Rectangle(size=resolution)

    def _java_capture_session_callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        event = MyCaptureSessionCallback.camera_capture_event.toString()
        logger.info("CALLBACK: capture event {}".format(event))

        self.java_capture_session = MyCaptureSessionCallback.camera_capture_session

        if event == "READY":
            logger.info("Doing READY actions")
            self.java_capture_session.setRepeatingRequest(self.java_capture_request.build(), None, None)
            Clock.schedule_interval(self._update_preview, 0.)

    def _update_preview(self, dt):
        self.java_preview_surface_texture.updateTexImage()
        self.preview_fbo.ask_update()
        self.preview_fbo.draw()
        self.output_texture = self.preview_fbo.texture
```

### The code i want implement from camera_android to color blind

```
    def grab_frame(self):
        """
        Grab current frame (thread-safe, minimal overhead)
        """
        with self._buflock:
            if self._buffer is None:
                return None
            buf = self._buffer.tostring()
            return buf
```

Comment: At worst you should be able to access the `pixels` attribute of the Texture providing the camera output, but there may also be a useful Android API function with more flexibility.

Comment: thanks , i will try